# R programming i need help finding sum of a list with 2 columns

Tags: r, sum

I need you help with this:

I have a list:

```
list(c(0,1), c(1,1), c(3,2))
```

how can i get the sum:

```
(0-1)+(1-1)+(3-2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This probably isn't the fastest way to calculate it, and it certainly uses more resources, but here's a completely different take on it:

```
> mylist = list(c(0,1), c(1,1), c(3,2))

> a = matrix(unlist(mylist), ncol=2, byrow=T)
> sum(a[,1]-a[,2])
```

Comment: matrices can be quite fast, I wouldn't be surprised if this is very speedy... especially if you changed the second line to `-diff(colSums(a))`

Comment: must be `byrow = TRUE`, or is your mylist different than OPs?

Comment: @adibender `mylist = list(c(0,1), c(1,1), c(3,2))` Yes, you're completely right, sorry!

Answer (score 7):

Not a big fan of `Reduce`, `do.call` is usually faster. In this case the `unlist` solution seems to have a slight edge:

***EDIT:*** @ds440 for the win!

```
                                                  expr    min      lq median      uq     max
1     do.call(sum, lapply(List, function(z) -diff(z))) 63.132 67.7520 70.061 72.7560 291.406
2                                             ds(List)  6.930 10.5875 11.935 12.7040  51.584
3 Reduce("+", lapply(List, function(x) -sum(diff(x)))) 78.530 81.6100 83.727 87.1915 855.355
4                             sum(-sapply(List, diff)) 88.155 91.4260 94.121 97.2005 955.442
5                     sum(-unlist(lapply(List, diff))) 57.358 60.4375 61.785 63.5170 145.126
```

Where `ds` is the approach by @ds440 wrapped in a function.

Comment: I think that in addition to speed, legibility is also a major factor to consider. Of these, I find `Reduce` to be least "reader friendly".

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
# Sum of the first differences of your list
> (Sumlist <- lapply(List, function(x) -sum(diff(x))))
[[1]]
[1] -1    # this is (0-1)

[[2]]
[1] 0    # this is (1-1)

[[3]]
[1] 1   # this is (3-2)

# Total sum of your list
> Reduce('+', Sumlist)   # this is (0-1)+(1-1)+(3-2)
[1] 0
```

Comment: +1 for reading more carefully than I did the first time around!

Comment: alternatively, you could do `diff(Reduce('+', List))`

Answer (score 3):

If that pattern, taking differences of first minus second element, is consistent, then just write an anonymous function in a call to `sapply` or `lapply`.

```
mylist <- list(c(0,1), c(1,1), c(3,2))
sapply(mylist, FUN = function(x) {x[1] - x[2]}) ## takes differences
sum(sapply(mylist, FUN = function(x) {x[1] - x[2]})) ## put it all together
```

This can also be achieved (as @AnandaMahto and @Jilber used) with the `diff` function. `diff(0, 1)` gives the 2nd minus the 1st, so we need to use `-diff` for 1st minus 2nd.

```
sum(-sapply(mylist, FUN = diff))
```

Comment: Thanks to @AnandaMahto for putting heads together